# Can standard operator be tupled or curried?

Tags: scala, function, operators, tuples

Following code works:

```
val ls = Seq("a", "b", "b", "c")

def strEq(a: String, b: String) = a == b
val detectChange = (ls zip ls.tail).map((strEq _). tupled)
```

Is it possible to use standard operator directly instead of creating strEq, something along the lines of?

```
val detectChange = (ls zip ls.tail).map(== _. tupled)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile on scala 2.11.8: `')' expected but '.' found.
[error]   val detectChange = (ls zip ls.tail).map(strEq _. tupled)`.

Comment: You need to remove the `.` after `strEq` for this to compile.

Comment: The closest thing I see (which is a bit more verbose) that is built in is `(ls zip ls.tail).map { case (x,y) => x == y }`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov That would be using postfix notation. I fixed it by enclosing in parentheses instead.

Comment: Or you could make your `strEq` like `def strEq(ab: (String, String)) = ab._1 == ab._2` and then `val detectChange = bla map strEq` but that's obvious... xD

Comment: @insan-e What I was trying with `strEq` was to create something very similar to standart operator `==`, so that I can demonstrate what I want to do with it. You are correct changing it to accept a tuple would avoid having to tuple it, but than there would be no analogy with `==`, which is not tupled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the special case of a 2-tuple, you can use:

```
scala> val ls = Seq("a", "b", "b", "c")
ls: Seq[String] = List(a, b, b, c)

scala> (ls, ls.tail).zipped.map(_ == _)
res0: Seq[Boolean] = List(false, true, false)
```

Other variants are

```
scala> (ls zip ls.tail).map{case (a,b) => a == b}
res2: Seq[Boolean] = List(false, true, false)

scala> (ls zip ls.tail).map{((_: String) == (_: String)).tupled}
res5: Seq[Boolean] = List(false, true, false)

scala> (ls zip ls.tail).map(((_ == _): ((String, String) => Boolean)).tupled)
res0: Seq[Boolean] = List(false, true, false)
```

but they are not easier to understand or simpler to write. Scalas type inference engine is not powerful enough to infer the correct type in the last case, therefore if the parameter types do not match you often have to fallback to use pattern matching.

Comment: I think `((_: String) == (_: String)).tupled` answers my title question "how to tuple a standard operator" - it shows how to get the function corresponding to the operator. It is more verbose than I hoped for, but it shows it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

the problem i think you're running into is that `==` is not a standard operator in the traditional sense, it's a method. it doesn't exist as a `Function2`, so there's no place to call it with `.tupled` that would yield what you're looking for. `((_: String) == (_: String)).tupled` works because it *is* a `Function2`.

not sure if the problem above is an example or something you actually need to do, but for fun, this also works:

```
ls sliding 2 map (_.toSet.size == 1)
```